# How to show text in TextArea on load?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, textarea, awt

How can I show text on load inside a textarea when the program is run?
Currently, text is shown on ActionPerformed, but i want it to show when the program is run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply pass the initial value to the constructor

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea("My default string");
```

It's the same for `JTextArea`.